# Is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty a_ib_j1_{\{X=a_i\}}1_{\{Y=b_j\}}=\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty $ true?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. Let $X,Y$ random variables. We suppose $\Omega $ discrete. We write $$X=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i\boldsymbol 1_{\{X=a_i\}}$$
and $$Y=\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k \boldsymbol 1_{\{Y=b_k\}}.$$

We want to write $X+Y$ as a sum of $\sum_{k}x_k\boldsymbol 1_{A_k}$. At a moment in the proof, they do :

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\boldsymbol 1_{\{X=a_k\}}\sum_{j=1}^\infty \boldsymbol 1_{\{Y=b_j\}}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_kb_j\boldsymbol 1_{\{X=a_k,Y=b_j\}}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kb_j\boldsymbol 1_{\{X=a_k,Y=b_j\}}.$$
In the last equality they permute the two sum. Don't we need condition to do that ? Like $\sum_{i,j}a_ib_j$ converge uniformly ? Because nothing has been mentioned at this subject.

Comment: @WillM. why do you need that?

Comment: My bad, I read non-negative random variables.

Comment: I don't understand you question, @Surb

Comment: Lebuesgue-Fubini-Tonelli theorem says iterated series of nonnegative functions can be commuted at will; all will diverge or all will converge to the same value (which is exactly the question OP is asking).

Comment: "At a moment in the proof, they do" Which proof in what book/notes are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

For a fix $\omega \in \Omega $, $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ib_j\boldsymbol 1_{\{X=a_i, Y=b_j\}}(\omega ),$$
is a finite sum.

Comment: It seems to me that the sum contains exactly one non-zero term if the $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ are distinct (i.e $a_i=a_j$ implies $i=j$)?

Comment: @irchans: yes exactly.